# Php script Not Working In Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

my php script is not working where as in same file html code is executing

```
<?php echo "testing"; ?><html><body>Testing1</body></html>
```

the following code writes Testing1 and php code is not been executed

My nginx configuration for php is

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

i have also changed the root directory

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

            root /home/sp/Desktop/mikz;
            index index.html index.htm index.php index.py;

            # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name 10.10.10.51;
}
```

Comment: while <?php phpinfo(); ?> shows full info

Answer (score 0):

What's the file extension, is it saved as .php or .html?

if .html please change it to .php to make it work.

Comment: File name is index.php

Comment: Can you try changing the order & put **index.php** to the front 
 
`"index index.html index.htm index.php index.py;"` to `"index index.php index.html index.htm  index.py;"`

**Restart nginx & have a re-test, if this works for you.**